# Calling base class constructor from derived class constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, derived-class

Here is the problem code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class baseClass
{
public:
    int objID;

    baseClass()
    {
        cout << "(1) Default constructor" << objID << endl;
    }

    baseClass(int ID)  // constructor
    {
        objID = ID;
        cout << "(2) Constructing base object with ID: " << objID << endl;
    }
};

class derivedClass : public baseClass
{
public:
    derivedClass(int ID)
    {
        baseClass(10);    // Line 1
        //baseClass(ID);  // Line 2
        cout << "(4) Constructing derived object with ID: " << objID << endl;
    }
};


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    derivedClass dcObj(1);

    return 0;
}
```

The problem I am having is with line 2 in the derivedClass constructor. It gives me the error that I am redifining a formal parameter. I know this is because compiler thinks I'm declaring a variable called "ID" of type baseClass. And I know that I should be calling this in the initializer list.

But my problem is why is line 1 working? Compiler interprets line 1 as an instantiation of a baseClass object with value 10. Then why is line 2 not working. I am passing an int in both cases. How is the compiler differentiating these two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an old rule, inherited from C, which does its best to drive programmers insane:

> if it can be a declaration, treat it as a declaration.

Coupled with the fact that C++ lets you insert redundant parentheses in many places - `int (x);` is a valid variable declaration - this means that

```
baseClass(ID);
```

is treated as

```
baseClass ID;
```

(There's no checking at this stage whether "ID" already means something, this is just grammar.)
In a later stage, when the parameter "ID" is known, this becomes a redefinition.

On the other hand,

```
baseClass 10;
```

can't possibly be a declaration, so it's taken to mean

```
 baseClass(10);
```

which constructs an unnamed `baseClass` instance and immediately throws it away.

Answer (score 1):

Line 1 is working because `baseClass` has a default constructor `baseClass()`, which is automagically called when your creating an instance of `derivedClass`. Your call to `baseClass(10)` in line 1 creates a *temporary object* of type `baseClass`, which is never used. This call is chosen because `10` is not a valid variable name, so it's interpreted as an argument to the function.

Answer (score 1):

The interpretation of the line

```
baseClass(ID);
```

as a declaration can be traced to the standard. From the C++ Draft Standard N3337 (emphasis mine):

> **6.8 Ambiguity resolution**
>
> 1 There is an ambiguity in the grammar involving *expression-statements* and declarations: An *expression-statement* with a function-style explicit type conversion (5.2.3) as its leftmost subexpression can be indistinguishable from a declaration where the first declarator starts with a (. **In those cases the statement is a declaration.** [ Note: To disambiguate, the whole statement might have to be examined to determine if it is an expression-statement or a declaration. This disambiguates many examples.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler does not recognize you calling derivatives,
he's just trying to make parameters, and for ID he tries to make a variable called ID, while with 10 he just makes a nameless temporary object.

Comment: The OP knows that it should be called in Initializer list, but asks for a specific compiler error. So this is not an answer

Answer (score 0):

*CASE_1 :-*

```
baseClass(ID);
```

This is giving you error as it's interpreted by compiler as

```
baseClass ID; <<< You're redefining ID.
```

*CASE_2 :-*

```
baseClass(10);
```

As `baseClass 10` interpretation would be non-sense, compiler treat this as constructor call.